# C program to simulate a submarine game

Tags: c, module, modularity

I am trying to make a battleship simulation game in C. What I am trying to do here is to get the starting and end point on the submarine on the board. For that I use a function. Now the problem is that the program crashes after getting 2 points.

```
int getsub(char* filename, Submarine* list)
{
    int subcount=0;
    int i=0;
    char* token;
    char line[100];
    FILE *fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("no file found");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(fgets(line,100,fptr))
    {
        if(isalpha(line[0])|| isalnum(line[0]))
        {
            ++subcount;
        }
    }

    list=malloc(sizeof(Submarine)*subcount);
    rewind(fptr);
    while(fgets(line,100,fptr)){
    if(isalpha(line[0]))
    {
        list[i]->start=malloc(sizeof(Point));
        token=strtok(line,"-");
        list[i]->start=TranslateCoordinate(token);
        list[i]->end=malloc(sizeof(Point));
        token=strtok(NULL,"-");
        list[i]->end=TranslateCoordinate(token);
        i++;
    }
    }
    return subcount;
}
```

That is on my source file. The other function I use is to get a coordinate (like A9) and turn it into a number between 0 and 9

```
Point TranslateCoordinate(char* c)
{
    Point newpoint;
    newpoint=malloc(sizeof(Point));
    int row=c[0];
    int column;
    newpoint->x=row-'A';
    if(c[1]== 1 && c[2]==0)
    {
        column=9;
        newpoint->y=column;
        return newpoint;
    }
    column=c[1];
    newpoint->y=column-'1';;
    return newpoint;
}
```

These are my structs:

```
struct Point_s
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Submarine_s
{
    Point start;
    Point end;
    int Life;
};

struct SubmarinePart_s
{
    Submarine* Sub;
    int IsHit; // 0 = not hit, <1 = exploded
};
```

and this is my main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"
#define BoardSize 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3){
        printf("Error not enough files");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char* P1setup=argv[2];
    char* P2setup=argv[3];
    Submarine* P1list;
    Submarine* P2list;
    getsub(P1setup,P1list);

    char Board1[BoardSize][BoardSize];
    char Board2[BoardSize][BoardSize];
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<BoardSize;x++){
        for(y=0;y<BoardSize;y++){
            Board1[x][y]='0';
        }
    }
    for(x=0;x<BoardSize;x++){
        for(y=0;y<BoardSize;y++){
            Board2[x][y]='0';
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and this is `header.h`:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Point_s* Point;
typedef struct Submarine_s* Submarine;
typedef struct SubmarinePart_s* SubmarinePart;
Point TranslateCoordinate(char* c);
int getsub(char* filename,Submarine* list);
void printpoint(Point p);
void printsub(Submarine s);

#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Looking at `int getsub(char* filename,Submarine* list)` you elsewhere have `typedef struct Submarine_s* Submarine;` and it won't be easy to follow how many levels of indirection you intend. Please do not `typedef` pointers.

Comment: Confusing indeed ;)

Comment: Get out the debugger please.

Comment: when i tried debugging all i got was an error in the malloc line
 `list[i]->start=malloc(sizeof(Point));` witch i dont really understand what could possibly be wrong with it

Comment: ...after compiling with all warnings enabled.

Comment: i allready thougt it might be the problem but when i chaged it the compiler gave me an error about using`.` in something that not a struct or a union

Comment: `list` may be a pointer, but when the index is added: `list[i]`, may it become an instance of the struct, in which case the notation should be `list[i].start = malloc(sizeof(Point));`. It is difficult to tell from trying to follow your code.  Consider creating a _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_, with emphasis on _minimal_ in this case.

Comment: Here: `getsub(P1setup,P1list);`  `P1list` is not initialized before being used

Comment: What is the contents of your file?

Comment: `#lines which starts with # you shall be able to ignore in your code`
`C1-F1`
`I2-I2`
`B3-D3`
`A5-A6`
`F5-F6`
`J4-J6`
`C7-C7`
`I8-I8`
`E9-E9`
`A10-B10`
also i tried setting it to `NULL` it made not diffrence

Comment: Is this just one line: `C1-F1 I2-I2...`, or is there a newline char between each: `C1-F1\nI2-I2\n...`?

Comment: there is a newline between each "word"

Comment: Again, in your line `getsub(P1setup,P1list);`, the first argument appears to be the filename of the input file, that you are apparently reading in from the command line.  It should be read from the buffer `argv`, but I do not see where you have ever assigned that input string, to the variable `P1setup` before using it.  Also again, step though your code in a debugger.  That action will likely help you to find the problems you are having.

Comment: Free hint: use `gdb` to trace your programs step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating the subelements of `list`. Remember that `Submarine` is typecasted from `typedef struct Submarine_s* Submarine;`. You allocated the main list, but did not allocate the member before you dereferenced it here `list[i]->start`

```
int getsub(char* filename, Submarine* list)
...

list=malloc(sizeof(Submarine)*subcount);
rewind(fptr);
while(fgets(line,100,fptr)){
if(isalpha(line[0]))
{
    list[i]->start=malloc(sizeof(Point));
```

you should have allocated list[i] first as sizeof(submarine_s) before you dereferenced it.

footnote: anyway, I don't agree with using the typedef that hid the pointer without any indication that the new type is a pointer. I would prefer if you typecasted it as `SubmarinePtr` instead.